# How to get todo table data in my custom validation in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I have got this error "Attempted to call an undefined method named 'getDoctrine" of class "AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsAlphanumericValidator'." when i am submitting the form.

I want fetch todo table data in validation but it give me above error.

```
 // src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/ContainsAlphanumericValidator.php
 namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
 use AppBundle\Entity\ToDo;
 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

 class ContainsAlphanumericValidator extends ConstraintValidator
 {
   public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
   {


        $todo = $this->getDoctrine()->
        getRepository('AppBundle:ToDo')->
        find('1');

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($todo);

        exit;
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) { 

          $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->setParameter('{{ string }}', $value)
            ->addViolation();
       }
  }
}
```

[image: See below image my folder structure.]

Comment: Not sure about symfony, just wanted to know does `ConstraintValidator` class contains `getDoctrine()`?

Comment: You must inject the EntityManager into your function. But I recommend to build your find function in the Repository directory and get your data from there.

Comment: @ElaAle Thanks for your help. Can you give me link for example of repository directory method ? Because i am new at symfony.

Comment: It's better to go to documentation of Repository https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/repository.html as an help you could create your custom query methods inside repository

Comment: This is the official documentation for Symfony 3.4, How to Create custom Repository Classes: 
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/repository.html. 
Please refer to the documentation for the Symfony version you use.

Comment: @ElaAle I have checked this documentation but still my problem is not solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is related to Dependency Injection. To work around, Symfony provide Service Container engine : https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Because by default symfony will do :

```
$validator = new ContainsAlphanumericValidator();
```

And you, you want to teach him to do :

```
$validator = new ContainsAlphanumericValidator($entityManager);
```

For that, you have to add on your `services.yml` :

```
AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsAlphanumericValidator:
    attributes:
        - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" #require EntityManager as first parameter of your construct
```

And update your class like this :

```
    class ContainsAlphanumericValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

     private $em;
     public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
            $this->em = $em;
     }
     public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
     {
                $todo = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:ToDo')->
                find('1');

                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($todo);

                exit;
                if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) { 

                    $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                        ->setParameter('{{ string }}', $value)
                        ->addViolation();
             }
     }
}
```

Comment: When i have updated your content in services.yml file then i am getting error  -> Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsAlphanumericValidator": argument "$em" of method "__construct()" has type "AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\EntityManagerInterface" but this class was not found.

Comment: you have forget to import EntityManager interface by adding in top of your file : `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;`

Comment: thanks for your help. I don't need update services.yml file and then i have updated my code ContainsAlphanumericValidator.php file with added use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface; method and my problem is solved. Thank you so much.